# How to validate mandatory associated model in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I've got myself confused about the right (or best) way to make sure the associated models are being sent via POST when creating a new User. Both approaches listed bellow are working.

```
User hasOne UserDetails
```

**Option 1**

POST data:

```
{
    "username": "loremipsum",
    "password": "123456",
    "UserDetails": {
        "first_name": "Lorem",
        "last_name": "Ipsum"
    }
}
```

PatchEntity UserDetail and add it to User Entity like this:

```
public function add () {

    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data(), [
            'associated' => [], 
            'validate' => true
        ]);
        $userDetail = $this->Users->UserDetails->newEntity($this->request->data());
        $user->user_detail = $userDetail;

    if ($this->Users->save($user, ['associated' =>['UserDetails']]))
    { 
...
```

**Edit 1:** if the UserDetails is not present on the $this->request->data(), the **UserDetails entity** will get validation errors.

**Option 2**

POST data:

```
{
    "username": "loremipsum",
    "password": "123456",
    "user_detail": {
        "first_name": "Lorem",
        "last_name": "Ipsum"
    }
}
```

Add user_detail validation into UserTable.php:

**Edit 2:** if I don't add user_detail validation, the request can be sent  without the associated model and it will be saved. Adding it makes sure there's a user_detail field on $this->request->data() and the **Users entity** is the one that will get the validation.

```
$validator
     ->requirePresence('user_detail', 'create')
     ->notEmpty('user_detail');
```

and patchEntity like this on UsersController.php:

```
public function add () {

    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data(), [
            'associated' => ['UserDetails'], 
            'validate' => true
        ]);

    if ($this->Users->save($user, ['associated' =>['UserDetails']]))
    { 
...
```

Are these approaches following Cake's conventions or there's a best/clean way to do it?

Comment: Option 2 is a better option. And it will give you validation errors for both `Users` and the associated model `UserDetails`.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator thanks for replying! Actually in both cases validation works because validation runs when creating the entity. The main difference here is the way code is written and data sent :)

Comment: option 1 is correct ..option 2 is not working it is validation only users model not userdetails..thanks man your really helpful

Answer (score 0):

The second option is the correct option for a few reasons IMO.

1. Validation should be on the Model it pertains to.
2. Validation should be expressive and explicit. If I'm the other guy reading this code, I could tell that validation is required for saving a user.
3. It is clearer and less prone to errors.
4. Matches with cake convention. I haven't seen in any of their examples where you would save one and then save the other. [Saving Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations)

Comment: I've edit my question to make it clear. Both cases the data is saved at once; the first one just adds UserDetails entity separately. The thing is: to  force UserDetails to be present on the request should I use the first or second option I gave? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to validate multiple model then you need to create multiple newEntity as per table.here is the working example for hasOne association.

```
 public function add() {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            $userDetail = $this->UserDetails->newEntity($this->request->getData()['user_detail']);
            $user->user_detail = $userDetail;
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect($this->referer());
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }
```